# How can I model a parallel flow that branches back into a regular flow?

Tags: bpmn

I have a BPMN process that should handle 2 alternative scenarios:

TaskA -> TaskB -> Last Task
OR
TaskA -> TaskX -> (TaskY and TaskB in parallel) -> Last Task

I can't find what's is the proper way to join the parallel tasks.

I have designed this solution, but it doesn't look fine to me:
for the first scenario, the parallel gateway looks like a fork rather than a join.

How should I design this case (without having to duplicate tasks) ?

[image: BPMN process]

Comment: "(TaskY and TaskX in parallel)" Did you mean "TaskY and TaskB in parallel"? I don't think you can do it like this; you will probably have to either duplicate Task B or put another guard before TaskY. Also, is it important that X is executed before B? You could make both X and Y parallel to B using an inclusive-or

Comment: Oups, yes you are right, there is a mistake and I'll fix it in the question. I want to avoid duplication, and order is important :) About the guard condition, should it better be after task B ?

Comment: Issue in your diagram is that "Task B" will only be available when both incoming transition are active. As Only one of them will be activate due to the usage of exclusive that will never happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following diagram do just what you want:
[image: Process diagram]

I use an inclusive gateway that will always take the transition that goes to "Task B" and based on condition also execute "Task Y" in parallel.
Same condition is also use to include or skip "Task X".

I create a [runnable version of this process](https://www.dropbox.com/s/alz4ph1rvvfn058/DemoDiagram-1.0.bos?dl=0) for Bonita BPM and it seems to behave like what you expect.

Comment: I like this solution cause its quite creative and clean at the same time. The requirement in the question to "avoid duplicate tasks" is normally not something I like to see as a requirement for process diagrams, because the readability comes first for me... But of course its nice to avoid duplication as long as one can avoid it without doing harm to readability. Thumbs up! (Btw I tend to believe it cannot be solved without duplicating anything - like in your case the "duplicated" condition expression)

Comment: Hi Antoine, this is a good solution. What designer did you use to draw your process ?

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I used [Bonita BPM Community Edition](http://www.bonitasoft.com/downloads-v2) to create this process